# Non advertised filetypes

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer

When I create an msi using VS2010, the shortcut and filetypes are all getting created as advertised. I am able to disable advertise property for shortcuts by setting DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS. However, the filetype is still advertised. How can i disable advertise for file types?

Thanks,
SAN

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many reasons that Microsoft has announced that VDPROJ is being [retired](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/09/installsite-microsoft-will-retire.html).

The only way to get what you want here is to write a bunch of postbuild processing of the resultant MSI to tweak it into what you want.  However I suggest you instead look at InstallShield or WiX instead.

Comment: What kind of postbuild processing can I do on the MSI to achieve this?

Comment: Execute SQL commands against the raw table data to massage the file extensions to behave the way you want.